# Screen Reader Accessible React chart library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

When building charts in React, there are some libraries, such as Victory and Nivo charts. I couldn't find one that is **screen reader accessible**, though.

That was the problem in one of Firefox's pages [about:protections](http://about:protections) (only available in Firefox browser). One of the developers solved it by turning the graph into a "fake table", using `role` and `aria-owns` attributes, along with other WAI's attributes. It also involved changing the HTML element's hierarchy.

[image]

My question is:
**Is there an existing chart React library that automatically makes it screen reader accessible?**

Comment: Hi Yogmel, this question is off topic for stack overflow, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This question will probably get closed as it is asking for opinion. You could just add a visually hidden table with the content after the charts and use aria-hidden on the chart itself. See https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/ on how to visually hide with CSS.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you very much for your response! Yes, I thought about doing that, but that might not be approved, so I was thinking about alternatives. Thanks anyway for your info and advice! It is good to have a confirmation from a professional in the field :)

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be approved as it won't add more than a couple of kb and has nearly 0 render time (as it is not painting). The way you suggest is better with converting the graph to a fake table but the 'hack' i suggested could actually be easier to maintain and I think you may struggle to find a library that creates pretty graphs, turns them into a fake table and presents them in the format you want (a lot of requirements!). If you find one then post it as an answer please as I love to stumble across new things to suggest to people!

Comment: Great, Graham! Thanks for your input. We agreed on creating a real table as an alternate view for all users. I will keep looking at libraries for future projects and will let you know, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but maybe this will help someone in the future.

I have helped write a library, Chart2Music, that can make charts accessible to screen reader users through interactive sonification.

I took the posted chart, and made a codepen of it using Chart.js and integrated Chart2Music:
https://codepen.io/chart2music/full/mdLLzON

Here is the code (I guessed at what the values in the chart would be):

```js
import {c2mChart} from "chart2music";

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const cc = document.getElementById("cc");

const labels = ["qua", "qui", "sex", "sáb", "dom", "seg", "Hoje"];

const data = [
  {
    purple: 0,
    blue: 0,
    green: 0
  },
  {
    purple: 50,
    blue: 50,
    green: 9
  },
  {
    purple: 60,
    blue: 33,
    green: 0
  },
  {
    purple: 300,
    blue: 120,
    green: 20
  },
  {
    purple: 100,
    blue: 45
  },
  {
    purple: 120,
    blue: 180,
    green: 6
  },
  {
    purple: 30,
    blue: 50,
    green: 12
  }
]

/* Set up data for Chart.js (visuals) */
const datasets = [
  {
    label: "purple",
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    borderColor: "purple",
    data: data.map((row) => (row.purple)),
    hoverBorderColor: "black",
    hoverBorderWidth: "5",
  },
  {
    label: "blue",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderColor: "blue",
    data: data.map((row) => (row.blue)),
    hoverBorderColor: "black",
    hoverBorderWidth: "5",
  },
  {
    label: "green",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    borderColor: "green",
    data: data.map((row) => (row.green)),
    hoverBorderColor: "black",
    hoverBorderWidth: "5",
  },
];
const config = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        minimum: 0
      }
    }
  }
};

const myChart = new Chart(canvas, config);


/* Wire up Chart2Music */
c2mChart({
  type: "bar",
  element: canvas,
  cc,
  axes: {
    x: {
      label: "Day",
      format: (index) => labels[index]
    }
  },
  options: {
    onFocusCallback: ({slice, index}) => {
      myChart.setActiveElements([{
        datasetIndex: labels.indexOf(slice),
        index
      }]);
      myChart.update();
    }
  },
  data: {
    purple: data.map((row, index) => {
      return {
        x: index,
        y: row.purple
      };
    }),
    blue: data.map((row, index) => {
      return {
        x: index,
        y: row.blue
      };
    }),
    green: data.map((row, index) => {
      return {
        x: index,
        y: row.green
      };
    }),
  }
});
```